# Sonoma 14.4: NFS shares automounted, but contents not visible

Tags: mount, folders, sonoma, nfs

On my Mac Studio I have three folders that I use as mount points for NFS shares. I manage the NFS mounts with NFS Manager. Up until recently (I suspect the update to Sonoma 14.4, but I'm not sure) everything worked OK, though I had to mount the shares explicitly from within NFS Manager.

Now the shares seem to be mounted automatically (whether at boot or on log-in, I cannot say). But their contents are not visible. When I try to tell NFS Manager to mount them it does nothing and produces no error message. And the contents remain invisible.

Interestingly, it appears that macOS uses low numbered inodes for mount points with a mounted share. This confused me at first.

My original question was based on a complete misunderstanding of the meaning of low-numbered inodes.

Somehow, in one of the updates to Sonoma, Something Changed and the folders were mounted but their contents not visible. I solved this by deleting the definitions in NFS Manager and redefining them. Now it all works again.